# Silverlight: binding to a static property defined in an ancestor class of the viewmodel

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, data-binding

In Silverlight, using MVVM I define a base class for related ViewModels and a list of possible values for a property defined in several child classes:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class MyViewModelBase
    {
        public static List<MyPropertyClass> MyPropertyValueList
        {
            get
            {
                if (myPropertyValueList == null)
                {
                    // fill the list
                }
                return myPropertyValueList;
            }
        }
        private static List<MyPropertyClass> myPropertyValueList = null;
    }
}
```

Now I define my ViewModel:

```
namespace MyNameSpace.MyChild
{
    public class MyViewModelChild
    {
        public MyPropertyClass MyProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return myProperty;
            }
            set
            {
                myProperty= value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("MyProperty");
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

And I bind to my ViewModel

```
<controls:ChildWindow
   x:Class="MyNameSpace.MyChild.MyChildEditor">
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyPropertyValueList, Mode=OneTime}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Then the binding fails for `MyPropertyValueList`.
But if the `MyPropertyValueList` is defined in the child class it works. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `MyPropertyValueList` as *static* property. It's not allowed in Silverlight.

Comment: Thanks, it works if I remove the static keyword. But why does it also work (using the static keyword) if the property is defined in the child class?